# Password not resetting on wordpress?

Tags: login, password, bug

I've repeatedly tried to reset my password on the Wordpress site according to their help site but it never changes despite not throwing an error. Attempting to reset my password through the 'forgot password' button will also give a 'successfully sent' message but the email never comes through.

My WordPress is version 4.6.14 running Blue Diamond theme. My website is hosted by HostGator if that could affect something.

If the solution involves code, please explain how to access that as I am not well versed in that realm.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the email address for your account is not correct. Try putting in your email address as the account name, and see if it recognizes that as a valid email address.

If not, then you will need to manually edit your user record in the database. That is assuming that you have authorized access to the hosting account, since you have to use a tool like myPHPAdmin to do that. Lots of googles/bings/ducks on how to edit the user table. (But do a backup first, just in case.)